# How to get all URL variable data in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

[By selecting search item and click on find tour i want to search particular categories but in print_r($_GET) i received on only one category id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iE5n.png)

[I want all four category id in $_GET variable to search for categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v40LJ.png)

I am using this code for dropdown:-

```
            $category = array(
                'show_option_all'    => 'Select Tour',
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'show_count'         => 0,
                'taxonomy'           => 'tour_category',
            ); 
            $tour_category = wp_dropdown_categories($category);
            $line = array(
                'show_option_all'    => 'Select cruise Line',
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'echo'               => 1,
                'taxonomy'           => 'genre',
            ); 
            $cruise_line = wp_dropdown_categories($line);
            $month = array(
                'show_option_all'    => 'Select Month',
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'echo'               => 1,
                'taxonomy'           => 'date_month',
            ); 
            $date_month = wp_dropdown_categories($month);
            $length = array(
                'show_option_all'    => 'Select Trip Length',
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'echo'               => 1,
                'taxonomy'           => 'writer',
            ); 
            $trip_length = wp_dropdown_categories($length);
```

Actually i want to make search based on these four categories.
My previously code is this:-

```
$text_field_label = _x( 'Search Tour', 'placeholder', 'adventure-tours' );



            printf(

                '<div class="%s">%s' . 

                    '<div class="form-block__item form-block__field-width-icon">' .

                        '<input type="text" %svalue="%s" name="s"><i class="td-search-1"></i>' .

                    '</div>' .

                '</div>',

                esc_attr( 'col-sm-' . $search_field_cells ),

                $is_show_label ? sprintf( '<div class="form-block__item-label 1">%s</div>', esc_html( $text_field_label ) ) : '',

                $is_show_label ? '' : sprintf( 'placeholder="%s" ', esc_attr( $text_field_label ) ),

                get_search_query()

            );
```

I convert it in dropdown with four different categories.

Comment: use cat1,cat2,cat3 and cat4 in your URL

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
$query  = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$param = array();

foreach( $query as $str)
{
  list($name, $value) = explode('=', $str, 2);
  $param[urldecode($name)][] = urldecode($value);
}
print_r($param);
```

Comment: How to add this in wordpress?

Comment: how to call print_r($_GET)

Comment: I want to get these all parameter in ajax in WordPress.

Comment: In DOM i get wc_add_to_cart_params
 
 Object { ajax_url="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",  wc_ajax_url="/?toursearch=1&cat=107&wc-ajax=%%endpoint%%",  i18n_view_cart="View Cart"

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I noticed here is that you are using the same name for all the four select boxes.

Because if you do not add `name` attribute in argument of `wp_dropdown_categories` function then it will automatically use default name i.e `cat`.

So add the different `name` attribute for each select box so that on submitting the form you will have four different select variables in `GET` query string as like below:

```
$category = array(
                'show_option_all'    => 'Select Tour',
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'show_count'         => 0,
                'name'               => 'cat-tour',
                'taxonomy'           => 'tour_category',
            ); 
            $tour_category = wp_dropdown_categories($category);
            $line = array(
                'show_option_all'    => 'Select cruise Line',
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'echo'               => 1,
                'name'               => 'cat-genre',
                'taxonomy'           => 'genre',
            ); 
            $cruise_line = wp_dropdown_categories($line);
            $month = array(
                'show_option_all'    => 'Select Month',
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'echo'               => 1,
                'name'               => 'cat-date',
                'taxonomy'           => 'date_month',
            ); 
            $date_month = wp_dropdown_categories($month);
            $length = array(
                'show_option_all'    => 'Select Trip Length',
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'echo'               => 1,
                'name'               => 'cat-writer',
                'taxonomy'           => 'writer',
            ); 
            $trip_length = wp_dropdown_categories($length);
```

Hope it helps.